# Translating Python into JavaScript — Lists?

Tags: javascript, python, translation

```
octopusList = {"first": ["red", "white"],
            "second": ["green", "blue", "red"],
            "third": ["green", "blue", "red"]}
squidList = ["first", "second", "third"]

for i in range(1):
    squid = random.choice(squidList)
    octopus = random.choice(octopusList[squid])

print squid + " " + octopus
```

Can anyone help me write this in JavaScript? I've got most of my program written into JavaScript but specifically how to get a list with lists in it written in JavaScript has me puzzled.  I'm new to programming in general, so thanks for putting up with my questions. :D

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I'd like to say that that `for i in range(1):` line is useless. It'll only execute the contents once, and you're not using `i`.

Anyway, the code you posted should work fine with a few tweaks in JavaScript. First you'll need to reimplement `random.choice`. You could use this:

```
function randomChoice(list) {
    return list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length)];
}
```

Now after that, it's simple:

```
var octopusList = {
    "first": ["red", "white"],
    "second": ["green", "blue", "red"],
    "third": ["green", "blue", "red"]
};
var squidList = ["first", "second", "third"];

var squid = randomChoice(squidList);
var octopus = randomChoice(octopusList[squid]);

// You could use alert instead of console.log if you want.
console.log(squid + " " + octopus);
```

Comment: `Math.random()` could return 1, in which case `randomChoice()` accesses a bad index.

Comment: @orip: [MDN says `Math.random` cannot return 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random): "Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to **but not including 1 (exclusive)**, which you can then scale to your desired range."

Answer (score 1):

```
js> octopusList = {"first": ["red", "white"],
               "second": ["green", "blue", "red"],
               "third": ["green", "blue", "red"]}

js> squidList = ["first", "second", "third"]
first,second,third

js> squid = squidList[Math.floor(Math.random() * squidList.length)]
third

js> oct_squid = octopusList[squid]
green,blue,red

js> octopus = oct_squid[Math.floor(Math.random() * oct_squid.length)]
blue
```

Answer (score 1):

> *...specifically how to get a list with lists in it written in Javascript has me puzzled.*

You can ( also )  create a list in with list in it in JavaScript like this:

```
var listWithList = [["a,b,c"],["d,"e","f"], ["h","i","j"]]
```

Because when you code in JavaScript

```
o = { "first" : ["red","green"],
      "second": ["blue","white"]}
```

You're actually creating a JavaScript object with two properties `first` and `second` whose values are a list ( or array ) with to elements each. This works just fine as you can see in icktoofay answer

Since that's a JavaScript object you could use this syntax to retrieve them

```
listOne = o.first;
listTwo = o.second;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer is oriented towards if it's already translated to JavaScript. The `{"a": "b", ...}` syntax in Python specifies a dictionary, not just a plain object. Also, to access elements in Python, you'd use `myList["first"]` and `myList["second"]`, etc. Finally, that list of lists code should work in Python, if you remove the `var` part.

Comment: :) :) yeap, that's because all the code in this answer is javascript :P not python :P I'm updating it

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module to translate data structures from Python to JSON format (which is valid Javascript) -- and viceversa, if you ever need to.  For example:

```
>>> octopusList = {"first": ["red", "white"],
...             "second": ["green", "blue", "red"],
...             "third": ["green", "blue", "red"]}
>>> print json.dumps(octopusList)
{"second": ["green", "blue", "red"], "third": ["green", "blue", "red"], "first": ["red", "white"]}
>>>
```

As you see, in this case the "translation" is just about an identity (the change of ordering in the dictionary entries [[in Python]] / object attributes [[in Javascript]] is irrelevant, as neither Python's dicts nor JS's objects have any concept of "ordering";-).